# Rails App throwing this error - output from console what does it mean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, debugging, afnetworking

Im debugging my rails app with an iOS client. Its a photo sharing and uploading app that Im following from

I finished the client part where the photos show up around the cleint. The next part which includes uploading images to the server from the client is where there are errors happening. Im using a 'puts @photos' statement in the controller to see the variable created after the upload.

This is the error that been thrown after a photo is uploaded from the device

```
 19:07:06 web.1  | Started POST "/photos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-11 19:07:05 -0700
 19:07:06 web.1  | Connecting to database specified by database.yml
 19:07:06 web.1  | Processing by PhotosController#create as JSON
 19:07:06 web.1  |   Parameters: {"photo%5Blat%5D"=>"37.785834", 
 "photo%5Blng%5D"=>"-122.406417", "photo"=>{"image"=>#
 <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff3cf0a3870 
 @original_filename="image.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", 
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[image]\"; 
 filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#
 <File:/var/folders/dh/1k2rdp_51yd2k43xzkc2pmdh0000gn/T/RackMultipart20120911-22662-1walqgi>>}}
 19:07:06 web.1  | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 55ms
 19:07:06 web.1  | ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: image):
 19:07:06 web.1  |   app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:51:in `new'
 19:07:06 web.1  |   app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:51:in `create'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a mass-assignment error on the `image` attribute of the `Photo` model. Just add:

```
attr_accessible :image
```

somewhere in the model and it should work. See the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible) for details.